# display Web app in android using Webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have a simon game I created in a webpage. I want to port this game into an android taking advantage of webview. So I have created an assets directory, and moved the index.html, css, and javascript files to this directory. However when running the app, it will only display the title of the page and some content. The simon board game doesn't display at all. How can I properly display the simon game board inside a webview. Here's the app running on the web.
http://pctechtips.org/apps/simon/
The code I imported into android is basically the same. I decided not to include the code for javascript as it would make this post too long. The code can be seen on the web app link above.

```
package org.pctechtips.simongame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/*
* SIMON SAYS GAME DEVELOPED IN JAVASCRIPT
* USING ANDROID STUDIO WEBVIEW TO DISPLAY
* HTML PAGE, WITH CSS AND JAVASCRIPT LOCATED
* IN ASSETS FOLDER
*/

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //url reference
        String simonUrl = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl(simonUrl);

    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.pctechtips.simongame.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-15dp"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Assets folder stuff
index.html css/stylesheet.css js/index.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <!--adding meta for android width-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simon Says</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhaijaan|Righteous" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>SIMON SAYS</h1>
      <div class="simon-container">
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="display">00</div>
          <div class="btn start-btn">START</div>
          <div class="btn stop-btn">RESET</div>
        </div>
        <div class="pads-container">
          <div id="0" class="pads green"></div>
          <div id="1" class="pads red"></div>
          <div id="2" class="pads yellow"></div>
          <div id="3" class="pads blue"></div>
        </div>    
      </div>   
    </div>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css file

```
body {
  background: url("http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/purty_wood.png");
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.simonBoard {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: solid 10px black;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  border-radius: 145px;
  box-shadow: -10px 10px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.pad {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  z-index: 8;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.green {
    background-color:#0a0;
    -moz-border-radius: 145px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 145px 0 0 0;    
}

.green-active {
  background-color: darkgreen !important;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 145px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 145px 0 0;
}

.red-active {
  background-color: darkred !important;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 145px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 145px;
}

.yellow-active {
  background-color: #e6d47e !important;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 145px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 145px 0;
}

.blue-active {
  background-color: darkblue !important;
}

.board-controls {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -6px 8px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.title {
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.display {  
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #342626;
}

.start, .strict {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.start {  
  background-color: darkred;
}

 .strict {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.switch-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.outter-switch {
  border: solid 2px black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: black;  
}

.outter-active {
  background-color: gray !important;
}

.inner-switch {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 15px;
  height: 12px;
  position: relative !important;
}

.inner-inactive {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Try using phonegap, I haven't tried it for games but works rely good for the most that i have tested it on.

Comment: do you know why it doesn't work on android studio. I mean the page is there, but the content is not displayed properly.